# Show that the n-sphere $\mathbb S^{n}$ is locally connected

Tags: general-topology, locally-connected

> A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is locally connected iff $\forall x\in X$ ,$\exists \{v_{i} : i\in I\}$ a familly of connected neighberhoods of $x$ such that $\forall u$ neighberhood of $x$ $\exists i\in I$ such that $v_{i}\in u$

> Show that the n-sphere $\mathbb S^{n}\subseteq \mathbb R^{n+1}$ (Product topology) is locally connected >

One idea is to fixe an element $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n+1})\in \mathbb S^{n}$ and then consider the familly $\mathbb B=\{S^{n}\bigcap \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}]a_{i},b_{i}[\}$ such that $x\in \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}]a_{i},b_{i}[$, we have $\forall B\in \mathbb B$, $B$ is a neighberhood of $x$ in $\mathbb S^{n}$, also $\forall v$ neighberhood of $x$ in $\mathbb S^{n}$, $v$ contains some $B$. Now I need to show that $B$ is connected, and I need some help with that please.

Comment: You could also use that it’s the quotient image of a locally connected space and as such locally connected.

Comment: the Book where this from did not introduce quotient spaces yet

Comment: The n-dimensional version of a stereographic projection provides a homeomorphism between $\mathbb S^{n}$ minus one point and $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: Sorry , but I don't know what a stereographic projection is.

Comment: @AbdellatifOuhaddou Embedd $\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as $\mathbb{R}^n\times \{0\}$ and consider the sphere centered at $(0, 0, ..., 1)$ of radius $1$. For $x$ from the sphere with $x\neq (0, 0, ..., 2)$  take the line from $(0, 0, ..., 2)$ to $x$, intersecting at some unique point of $\mathbb{R}^n\times \{0\}$. This defines a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^n$ without a point. This is stereographic projection.